# Google Drive SDK (java) slow on query request for Files List

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive SDK to query and retrieve files using a service account (access and refresh tokens, etc).  **The issue is not that it's not working, but that the first query request, after a certain period of time, is significantly slower that the proceeding requests.**  I've tried "priming the connection" by retrieving the Drive.About before doing any "heavier" requests, but that doesn't seem to help.  Additionally, I have implemented partial field responses, as per Drive best practices.  Any ideas or additional information needed?

- Please note that static Drive service variable is cached after its initial retrieval and is reused in a singleton service.

** By slow I mean 2000+ ms, without any exponential back-off, the average response time is typically between 100-200 ms

Sample:

**Retrieve Files**

```
Drive service = retrieveGoogleDriveService();

Files.List request = service.files().list()
    .setQ(q + " AND trashed=false AND hidden=false")
    .setFields(fields);

FileList files = request.execute();
```

**method: retrieveGoogleDriveService**

```
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory, new FileReader(new java.io.File(Home.class.getResource(CLIENT_SECRET).toURI())));

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setClientSecrets(clientSecrets)
    .build()
        .setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN)
        .setRefreshToken(REFRESH_TOKEN);

service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
               .setApplicationName([app name])
               .build();
```

**Thank you ahead of time**

Comment: Additional information:

The exception thrown during execute(): is NoHttpResponseException and the message is "The target server failed to respond".  Using exponential back-off and after each wait the same exception and message is thrown

Comment: Do you see similar response times using the "try it" tool in the documentation?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't have an issue with the response times.  The issue is related to the first request/response after an unknown period of time.  As noted above, the target server is not responding on the initial request, but then becomes "responsive" on the next request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to using ApacheHttpTransport, instead of the recommended GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport().

Comment: **From:**
ApacheHttpTransport httpTransport = new ApacheHttpTransport();

**To:**
HttpTransport serviceHttpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();